# page loads twice due to js code

Tags: asp.net

I have this div inside a repeater, where i set the class, onmouseover and onmouseout properties from code behind:

```
<div id="Div1" runat="server" class="<%# getClassProduct(Container.ItemIndex) %>" onmouseover="<%# getClassProductOver(Container.ItemIndex) %>" onmouseout="<%# getClassProductOut(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
```

codebehind:

```
 public String getClassProduct(Object index)
{
    int indexItem = Int32.Parse(index.ToString());
    if (indexItem == 3)
        return "produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem lastbox";
    else
        return "produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem";
}

public String getClassProductOver(Object index)
{
    int indexItem = Int32.Parse(index.ToString());
    if (indexItem == 3)
        return "this.className='produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem_ lastbox'";
    else
        return "this.className='produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem_'";
}

public String getClassProductOut(Object index)
{
    int indexItem = Int32.Parse(index.ToString());
    if (indexItem == 3)
        return "this.className='produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem lastbox'";
    else
        return "this.className='produs_box produs_box_wrap overitem'";
}
```

Well, the problem is that, my Page_Load is fired twice, and there i have some code which i want to execute only ONCE:

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    { ..code to execute once }
```

This code is fired initially, and after the page is rendered, it is called again, and executed again due to that js...

Anyone can recommend a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** happens only in Firefox. On chrome, it works fine...

**"Solution"**: deactivated YSlow....just "horrible".

Comment: You should post the whole page, so we can see the context, which is likely where the important information exists.

Comment: Well, the hole page (aspx) has 350 lines of cod. If i only comment that div from above, all it's working great.

Comment: I suggest watching it in the debugger and check the stack trace to see who is calling the code twice.

Comment: If this changes based on the browser, then it sounds like somethng in your content is causing the browser to reload. What is the content of the div? You code only shows how you handle the appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use [`OnItemCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcreated%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) event to do that?

Assuming, the div is part of each item, you could trap into the event & do a `FindControl` on the `Item` to get the handle to `div`. Check for `ItemIndex` & assign the class as you need to in code-behind.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Hi, done in OnItemCreated event but still the problem persists.

Comment: Do you have any firefox addon that could be causing the refresh? What is the value of `Page.IsPostBack` when the page loads 2nd time?

Comment: Hi. Page.IsPostBack is false for the 2nd time too. I deactivated firebug, seems the problem still persists...

Comment: EVRIKA!! YSlow was activated!!!!! :(( so it asked for a second request. Unbelievable!!!! Thanks. i check yours as anwer due to your "add on" related question!

Comment: Wow. I will suggest using the event way of attaching class, if that helps. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the `Response.Redirect` with `Server.Transfer` because it was suggested to be the *new way of doing things*. Since then, the pages load twice and the Back-button in Chrome returns to the previous page and immediately back to the current page.
I replaced the `Server.Transfer` with `Response.Redirect`, and all was back to normal. I hope this helps someone.