# Asp.net LoginUrl page_load is fired twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, pageload

i have a problem with page_load event of my loginUrl page.

To exclude all the other problem i created a pageTest completely empty

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestPage_NoMaster.aspx.cs" Inherits="project.TestPage_NoMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in my web.Config i have this configuration:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="login" loginUrl="~/TestPage_NoMaster.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

I don't understand why Page_load event is fired twice when the web application starts.

Someone can help me?

back end code:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 namespace project
 {
     public partial class TestPage_NoMaster : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             String prova = "Hello :)";
         }
     }
 }
```

UPDATE:

**in the intelliTrace i have some exception:
- impossible load file or assembly App_web...filenotfoundException
- System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
**

Comment: I have you tried running it in the debugger, putting in a breakpoint, and inspecting the call stack?

Comment: What `page_load` event?

Comment: page_load function..

Comment: He means show it. There's no point showing us the front end HTML when the problem is on the back end code!

Comment: Post the code in TestPage_NoMaster.aspx.cs.  You could be inheriting from something that also calls page_load...or one of several other possibilities.

Comment: back end is empty too :D i update the question with it now

Comment: From a breakpoint to another a have some exception (i see it now in the intellitrace) : impossible load file or assembly ....

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785825/page-load-is-firing-twice-in-asp-net-page ?

Comment: the solution in that link are excluded, because my page i completely empty.. and i delete the  AutoEventWireup="true" too.. is not a duplicate